# Why do cast hashsets not allow comparisons?

Tags: c#, hashset, derived

I am using identifier classes in my project to keep track of certain variables. During writing of unit tests for these classes I noticed that the set actions did not behave as expected.

A minimal example to reproduce this problem is the following:

```
public void HashDerivedTest()
{
    var setA = new HashSet<DerivedTestNumber>
    {
        new DerivedTestNumber(1),
        new DerivedTestNumber(2),
        new DerivedTestNumber(3)
    }.Cast<TestNumberId>().ToHashSet();
    var setB = new HashSet<TestNumberId> { new TestNumberId(1), new TestNumberId(3), new TestNumberId(5) };

    var setAHashes = setA.Select(x => x.GetHashCode()).ToList();
    var setBHashes = setB.Select(x => x.GetHashCode()).ToList();

    var intersect = setA.Intersect(setB).ToSet();
    Assert.AreEqual(2, intersect.Count); // This will return 0.
    Assert.IsTrue(intersect.Contains(new TestNumberId(1))); // This will return false.
    Assert.IsTrue(intersect.Contains(new TestNumberId(3))); // this will return false.
}

private abstract class BaseNumberClass<TVal>
    where TVal : IEquatable<TVal>, IComparable<TVal>
{
    public BaseNumberClass(TVal value) => this.Value = value;

    public TVal Value { get; }
    
    public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();
}

private class TestNumberId : BaseNumberClass<long>
{
    public TestNumberId(long id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }
}

private class DerivedTestNumber : TestNumberId
{
    public DerivedTestNumber(long id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

I am fully aware that Hashsets do not implement covariance, but IEnumerables should. Thus casting in this way should create a copy of the original list with the new list having the same type.

Why does this not behave like this? And is there somehow to make it behave as expected?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of your scenario mentioned in your [comment on your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748743/why-do-cast-hashsets-not-allow-comparisons/76748939?noredirect=1#comment135329637_76748939). These are crucial information about how the `Equals()` method should look like. Provide a detailed and complete example of the different sub classes you have with all the different hierarchies you have. Also explain how/when these instances should equal and when not. If possible, provide a [mcve] which shows all the combination you have.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference:

It seems this has to do with behaviour of the hashset comparison which will check on equality if the hashcodes of two objects are equal, but they do not have the same class.

The method for solving this is to implement the equals so it checks for inheritance.

This can be done by adding the following equality test:
This issue can be solved by adding the following equality to the base class:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return true;

    if (other is null)
        return false;

    // This tests for inheritance from both sides of the comparison.
    // Direct comparison of the subclass is not allowed as this would always be this class.
    return (other.GetType() == this.GetType() ||
            other.GetType().IsSubclassOf(this.GetType()) ||
            this.GetType().IsSubclassOf(other.GetType())) &&
           this.Value.Equals(((BaseNumberClass<TVal>)other).Value);
}
```

Comment: Implementing the `Equals()` method like that (with the `IsSubclassOf()` check) breaks the required transitive property of equivalence, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

Comment: That depends on the structure of the class. If the base class is abstract that is not the cases as a direct instance of the base class is not possible.
I will update my question (and my corresponding code) to reflect that detail.

Comment: @Progman can you validate that in this case this solution is (one of) the correct one(s)?

Comment: It can also break when you have other non-abstract classes in the hierarchy which are the base classes of other two sub classes. Also, your method isn't sealed in this particular case, which means sub classes could break the symmetry property of `Equals()`. This is also something to consider. It might be easier to add a sealed `Equals()` method in the base class which checks with the `is` operator if the given argument is a `BaseNumberClass<TVal>` instance and then check the `Value` property.

Comment: @Progman
That is not applicable in this case as there are multiple different hierarchies build on top of this base class. These are not allowed to communicate.
So for example there is a class A which has derived classes B and C, and a classed D with derived classes E and F. A, B & C can be equal to eachother and D,E & F can be eachotherm, but all can never be equal to the other group.